# Strategy to easily update incoming external links to an excel workbook

Tags: microsoft-excel

Lets say you have 2 workbooks Name "PrivateWorkbook" and "PublicWorkbook"

PublicWorkbook is accessible to everybody in our company.

PrivateWorkbook is only accessible to managers.

There are external links from PublicWorkbook to PrivateWorkBook.

When PrivateWorkbook is updated, there are cells in PublicWorkbook that should reflect those changes.

However the only way PublicWorkbook's links get refreshed is if a manager opens Publicworkbook after editing PrivateWorkbook.

If a non-manager opens PublicWorkbook first, the links can't be refreshed as he doesn't have rights to open PRivateWorkbook.

Is there anyway I can get PublicWorkbook updated when a manager edits Privateworkbook without forcing them to manually opening publicworkbook?

Comment: Would you be okay with a "Refresh Links" button in `PublicWorkbook`? I think you could have something like that that opens `PrivateWorkbook` invisibly just long enough to update the links and then closes it. There will probably be some further details to work out, but I think this could solve the problem.

Comment: The users who access PublicWorkbook don't have permissions to access the PrivateWorkbook file.

Comment: Having a button in PrivateWorkbook that opens PublicWorkBook momentarily might work.

Comment: How are file permissions handled? Are the workbooks located on a server? Passwords?

Comment: Workbooks are located on the server, in a share that isn't accessible to staff.

Comment: Use VBA's [`Workbook_BeforeClose`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8987930/excel-control-events-trigger-on-application-close) event in your private file to automatically open and save the public file. The event is triggered when your manager closes the private file. You can also check if there are changes made or not. If not, do nothing

Comment: I took your suggestion by tied into the Workbook_AfterSave event. Write your comment up as an answer and I'll upvote it

Comment: @nixda, see comment above :)

Comment: @Aheho, if you want some one to read your comment, use the `@` and their name, example: @daverook

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use VBA together with its *Workbook_BeforeClose* event in your private file to automatically open, save and close the public file. The event is triggered when your manager closes the private file. Let the manager confirm the update with a simple yes-no prompt.

Note the `UpdateLinks:=True` parameter which silently updates all external links in your public file

#### Example code (must be placed under ThisWorkbook)

```
Private Sub Workbook_BeforeClose(Cancel As Boolean)

    Dim wb As Workbook
    FilePath = "C:\public.xls"

    If MsgBox("Update " & FilePath & " ?", vbYesNo) = 6 Then
        Set wb = Workbooks.Open(FilePath, UpdateLinks:=True)
        wb.Close SaveChanges:=True
    End If

End Sub
```